# uninitialized constant BooksController::Books

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a sample app and trying to use will_paginate gem.

App/Controllers/books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def index
    #@books = Book.all
    @books = Books.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
    end
end
```

App/views/index.html.erb

```
<% for book in @books do %>
  <h2><%=h book.title %></h2>
  <p><%= book.thoughts %></p>
  <%= will_paginate @books %>
<% end %>
```

when i load application i get the error in title. am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restart the server after i installed gem.
Its working now

Answer (score 0):

Model class names are singular. You used `Books.paginate`, whereas it should be `Book.paginate`.

Since you are using the wrong class name, Ruby complains because the class is not defined.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that earlier but then i get error undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x007fd533cd44d8>

Comment: It means that method is not defined on the Book model. It's likely you did not properly include the `will_paginate` gem as a dependency.

Comment: I added gem 'will_paginate' in environment.rb and tried to run $ sudo rake gems:install and it says 'Dont know how to build task rake'

Answer (score 0):

`@books = Book.all.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)`

You called the `paginate` method on `Books` instead of `Book.all`